# wordpress random widget widget

Tags: widgets

am planning a random widget for widgets that uses jquery to fade in each widget from the top (a total of 12 displayed 3 at a time). The widget creation and animation I can handle but falling short on how it would choose a random order and display the 3 at a time. how can I achieve this?

Any help on how to display random data and then pull the next random data would be amazing.

thanks

Comment: current status of code is: working, have tried dumping all $output1-12 into an array and have the code display 3 at a time using rand function but didnt work, tried a simple call to action to start and that didnt work. Am kind of new to widgets and need the help.

Comment: I didn't mean to ask for a description of whether your current code "works". I meant to ask you to simply edit the code itsself into the question. ;)